# R.anim.filename highlights red

Tags: java, android, xml

i have this xml file in Android Studio, called startup.

I have this line

```
final Animation SplashAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.startup);
```

I am trying to define a startup.xml file in this line but Android Studio can't find it.

But Android Studio highlights startup with a red and i don't know why?
Android Studio only finds it when i type R.animator.startup, but again that underlines with a red line.

Any help on this problem?

Comment: what is the directory under the res folder where you have your animation xml file startup?

Comment: sorry, i have fixed it. it was the name of the directory which was misspelt.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good luck!

Comment: Can you kindly accept the answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

Read from here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question

From my comment: "Renaming the animation folder to res/anim solved your issue"